# Whats the difference between applying Correlation and DTW in a Time Series

Tags: time-series, correlation, clustering

I have a Financial Time Series from a database and intend to cluster the time series based on their similarity. How would it be different to cluster them based on their pairwise Correlation and cluster them using DTW. Which is recommended option between the two

Comment: What does DTW stand for?

Comment: Dynamic Time Warping. A great dissimilarity measure for time-series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) and correlation capture very different aspects of similarity between two time-series. Which one to choose depends on what you are interested in - an information that you did not provide in your question.

Yet I will give an example which might help to clarify the difference for you. 
Assume you consider the following two time-series as equal:

```
a = [1,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]    
b = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,3,2,1]
```

[image: visualization]

For this example, the DTW Distance - computed as in [here](http://alexminnaar.com/time-series-classification-and-clustering-with-python.html) - returns: `DTWDistance(a,b) = 0`, since DTW Distance allows shift in time and effectively compares the shape of the time-series giving little importance to stretching. Whereas the correlation here returns such as `np.corrcoeff(a,b) = -0.33471074`

We want to cluster objects together that are similar. Therefore we use a dissimilarity measure, which yields 0, if two objects are equal, a higher value, the more different they are. Most relevant attributes of such a dissimilarity measure would be the metric requirements such as in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space). For correlation - assuming you mean pearsons correlation coefficient - these requirements are not met. Therefore I would suggest to use DTW. Yet there might be some applications in which clustering based on correlation could yield great result.

Best way to go: Try both and compare the results. Then choose the one which fits your expectation.

Comment: Thanks your answer,it indeed has been of great help. To add on more information to my question, Lets say there is a collection of  Time series observations of returns of instruments(of about 10,000), with irregular intervals. I will need to cluster them based on their past performances with similar trend. So firstly does correlation be advised in such a situation of irregular intervals. Even if DTW is to be used can I decide upon the level of similarity within a cluster(allowing only very highly similar series to be clustered together)

Comment: I think an additional issue with using time series cross correlation as a metric is that it depends on the lag that you use. For example, Two sinewave time series could be exactly the same but exactly opposite if the lag = 1/2 the wavelength which gives a 0 cross correlation. Perhaps an approach maybe to take the average cross correlation as the measure..Either way, its not a convenient distance metric.